# How to generate unique URLs for a user and use the parameters to authenticate validity of link?

Tags: node.js, authentication, url, cryptography, unique

So this might be a strange one and a rather specific use case.

We have a client who does not wish to share client data so we need to create a unique link (maybe something like https://www.mywebsite.com/?id=DFJSDF2323IONDFGFD3) for each of their users and the users can see this link once they sign-in to our client's platform.

This link will redirect the user to our platform and we need to take the parameter (id) from the url and validate if the link is legitimate and only then they can use our platform.

I'm looking for help on how to implement this. What sort of encryption/decryption or authentication mechanism would be suitable here?

Comment: Essentially you are validating a password.  There is a lot of advice on how to create a secure password hash, with salt and stretching

Answer (score 0):

You can generate UUIDs.

Here's code that can help you generate different UUIDs all day, every day.
https://gist.github.com/jed/982883